# What does ReSharper think I'm trying to do with readonly?

Tags: c#, resharper, c#-7.2

While writing C#, I accidentally missed the `= new List<T>()` off a collection initialiser, meaning that I wrote this incorrect code:

```
readonly List<int> x
{
    1,2,3
}
```

However, besides the obvious syntax errors, ReSharper annotated the `readonly` keyword saying that it was a "C# 7.2 language feature".

[image]

What did ReSharper think I was trying to do with `readonly`? Are there new features related to this coming in C# 7.2?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-2

Comment: @Evk: So... which one is it?

Comment: @Evk I read that and didn't understand which one applied to the question. Care to elaborate as an answer?

Comment: `readonly struct` ?

Comment: Sorry a misread question a bit. But anyway this syntax is not valid in C# 7.2 also, so we can only guess what Resharper means. Probably readonly struct indeed, though I cannot reproduce it with my (last) version of resharper. Only if I add `readonly struct List<int> x` it will suggest that it's C# 7.2 feature.

Comment: Maybe `ref readonly` to indicate that a method returns its value by reference but doesn't allow writes to that object.

Comment: Does this code snippet alone produce this message or in combination with lines above or/and below?